# Is Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() applicable for multiple objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, synchronization, scheduledexecutorservice

Im making a small game where space-ships fire in intervalls of x seconds.

In this method Im spawning lasers the enemies can fire. In order to time their shots
Im using

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

but Im not sure if that´s right when there can be multiple enemy-space ships on the board at once.
(Since its using one thread and then waits x seconds before using that thread for that task again).

So summarized: is this the right way to time an event for multiple objects or is it only working for one object a a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some more performance optimized versions, but the aproach is fine for the beginning.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = s.scheduleAtFixedRate(shoot, 0, enemy.getRate(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Will be scheduled once impediatly, and then every `getRate()` seconds until you call `future.cancel()`.

Only one shot is evaluated at a single moment, thats fine if the caclculation is rather quick, and you don't call `Thread.sleep()` in the `Runnable`.